# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку текст открывался в textarea и его можно было бы изменить?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку текст открывался в textarea и его можно было бы изменить?

[image: картинка]

Comment: Что получилось до сих пор? Добавте в вопрос ваш код.

Comment: дополните вопрос своим кодом

Answer (score 3):

Ну например так

```js
$('#puk').on('click', function() {
  $('#editable').attr('contenteditable', true);
});
```

```css
#editable {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border:1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 5px 4px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="editable">
  текст 1 текст 2 текст 3
</div>

<input id="puk" type="button" value="чик">
```