# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку текст открывался в textarea, и его можно было бы изменить?

Tags: php, javascript, css

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку текст открывался в textarea, и его можно было бы изменить?

[image: картинка]

Comment: зачем плодить вопросы ??? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746821/Как-сделать-чтобы-при-нажатии-на-кнопку-текст-открывался-в-textarea-и-его-можно